# how can I filter the list of list by first item in inner list?

Tags: jinja2

I have a list of list like this `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`

I want to select the item by the 1st item of inner list with jinja2 filter to achieve similar result as in python `[i for in a if i[0] in somelist ]`. I know if it is a list of dict, I can use `selectattr('first key', 'in', somelist)`. But I have no idea how to select based on the N-element of inner list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in filter that would do that in Jinja2, but you can use a `for` loop instead to achieve the same effect.

For example:

```
{% set a = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]] -%}
{% set somelist = ['b', 'e'] -%}
{% for i in a -%}
  {%- if i[0] in somelist %}found {{i}}{% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

would output:

```
found ['b', 2]
```